# Is this inequality trivial?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, complex-numbers

Let  $z = (z_1,z_2)\in \mathbb C^2$, $|z| \leq 1$. Then
$$
\left( |z_1|^2 - |z_2|^2 \right)^2 \leq \left( |z|^2 + (z_1 \bar z_2 -\bar z_1 z_2 )^2   \right)  \left( |z|^2 - (\bar z_1  z_2 - z_1 \bar z_2 )^2   \right)
$$
where $\bar z_k$ denotes complex conjugate.

I got this inequality by applying the Robertson–Schrödinger uncertainty relations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Robertson.E2.80.93Schr.C3.B6dinger_uncertainty_relations), a result about self-adjoint operators on Hilbert spaces to the Hilbert space $\mathbb C^2$ and the self adjoint operators \begin{bmatrix}
   0       & 1 \\
    1       & 0  \\
\end{bmatrix}
 and 
\begin{bmatrix}
   0       & -i \\
    i       & 0  \\
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Where did it arise?

Comment: Just added some motivation to the post.

Comment: @πr8 I just fixed a mistake (had to many squares on the LHS) although this doesnt address your comment. Let me check my work again.

Comment: @πr8 Notation question...how is $z \in \mathbb  C^2$ equal to the product of two complex numbers?

Comment: Thanks @Hamton for spotting a mistake on my part. Note that upon letting $z_1=re^{i\theta},z_2=se^{i(\theta+x}$, the inequality becomes $|r^2-s^2|^2\le|r^2+s^2+4r^2s^2\sin^2 x||r^2+s^2-4r^2s^2\sin^2 x|=|(r^2+s^2)^2-(2rs\sin x)^4|=|(r^2-s^2)^2+4r^2s^2(1-r^2s^2\sin^4 x)|$, which seems to be true even in the slightly more general setting of $|z_1||z_2|\le1$.

Comment: Oh okay that's interesting.